# On a 12c R2 RAC DB, Oracle instance information on crsctl is shown incorrectly

Tags: oracle-12c, rac

crsctl status output is showing incorrect information for ora.***.db.
Instance 1 and 2 are running on Node1 and Node2 respectively but crsctl status shows as below

As we can see below, its showing Instance 1 is running on Node2 and Instance 2 is running on Node1.

```
ora.stgcdb.db
      1        ONLINE  ONLINE       node02                 Open,HOME=/u01/app
                                                             /oracle/product/12.2
                                                             .0/dbhome_1,STABLE
      2        ONLINE  ONLINE       node01                 Open,HOME=/u01/app
                                                             /oracle/product/12.2
                                                             .0/dbhome_1,STABLE
```

When we see srvctl status for database, it shows as below :

```
[oracle@node01 ~]$ srvctl status database -d stgcdb
Instance stgcdb1 is running on node node01
Instance stgcdb2 is running on node node02
[oracle@node01 ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

With a valid support contract, you can check this:
[Database Instance Resources Sequence in "crsctl stat res -t" Output Mismatches With Output of "olsnodes -n" (Doc ID 1580894.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1580894.1)

> The node ordering is not guaranteed to be same as instance number
>   ordering. CRSCTL output in sorted order is not guaranteed.
>
> ...
>
> This is expected behavior.